# Moments of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Fix a smooth $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ compactly supported function $f$ with the support of $f$ being the unit interval $(-1,1)$ and with $\hat{f} \geq 0$. Is it true that as $k$ goes to infinity
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} x^{2k} \cdot \hat{f}(x) dx \gg (2k)! \cdot A^{-k}
$$
for some large fixed $A > 0$?
I think the answer is affirmative, but I haven't been able to fully justify it to myself. I'm posting this in the hope that there is a slick and short argument.

Comment: Bernstein's inequality for bandlimited functions (in your case $\hat{f}$ is bandlimited) might be relevant to you (gives you $L^p$ bounds on the derivatives of $\hat{f}$... okay maybe not relevant at all, actually), and it is an upper bound...   Also, $f=0$ is a trivial counterexample, so something needs tweaking (perhaps the bump satisfies $\|f\|_1 = 1$ or some other normalization)

Comment: Support equal to (-1,1) means that the function is non-zero on this open interval, so $f = 0$ is not an admissible counterexample...

Comment: Since $\widehat{f}$ is entire, I was thinking of deforming the contour but haven't gotten very far so far...

Comment: Ah okay. My thought was to use repeated integration by parts to give you something of that form? You can probably use the fact that $\hat{f}$ is a Schwartz class function (compactly supported F.T. shows smoothness, smoothness of F.T. shows exponential decay). I do not know the role of $k^{-A}$ though.

Comment: Hm... I'm actually starting to doubt this lower bound... Let me think some more about it.